What is the correct way of defining a continuous-time state space with a quaternion as part of the state in Drake?
I'm trying to set up a simulation of the dynamics of a quadcopter in Drake in C++. I've drawn a lot of inspiration from the example in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/quadrotor/quadrotor_plant.cc, however, in that example the attitude is represented with Euler angles, and I prefer to use a quaternion. The problem is that I have yet to figure out how I tell the integrator that it needs to ensure that the quaternion needs to be normalized. Is it possible to use quaternions in a state with other "normal" states, like position etc, in Drake? And if so, how?
The closest I have come is to use DeclarePerStepUnrestrictedUpdateEvent to normalize the quaternion at every time step, but when logging the state output from the quadcopter plant, the quaternion is constantly unnormalized, although it never drifts to far from unity norm. Using DeclarePerStepPublishEvent and this function
auto QuadcopterPlant::normalize_quaternion(const drake::systems::Context<double>& ctx) const
    -> drake::systems::EventStatus
{
    Quadcopter::State::Vector state_vec = ctx.get_continuous_state_vector().CopyToVector();
    state_vec.segment<4>(3).normalize();
    const_cast<drake::systems::Context<double>&>(ctx).get_mutable_continuous_state_vector().SetFromVector(state_vec);
    return drake::systems::EventStatus::Succeeded();
}

helps since the normalization is after the integration step, but this involves a const_cast, which seems far from ideal...
For my system, this main function should hopefully give some insight into how I build the simulation now. The class QuadcopterPlant inherits from LeafSystem:
int main()
{
    auto builder = DiagramBuilder<double>{};
    // Create the simple system.
    auto quadcopter = std::make_unique<quadsim::quadcopter::Quadcopter>(quadsim::quadcopter::Quadcopter::Parameters{});

    auto system = builder.AddSystem<quadsim::quadcopter::QuadcopterPlant>(std::move(quadcopter));

    auto logger = LogVectorOutput(system->get_output_port(0), &builder);

    auto diagram = builder.Build();

    // Create the simulator.
    Simulator<double> simulator(*diagram);
    // Set the initial conditions x₀.
    Eigen::VectorXd init_state = Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(quadsim::quadcopter::Quadcopter::State::DIM);
    init_state(3) = 1.0;
    simulator.get_mutable_context().get_mutable_continuous_state().SetFromVector(init_state);

    // Simulate for 10 seconds.
    simulator.AdvanceTo(10.0);

    const auto sim_log = logger->FindLog(simulator.get_context());
    log_to_file(sim_log);

    return 0;
}

Main thing is perhaps that I don't use MultibodyPlant, which to me seems like an overkill in this case, but maybe that is necessary?
EDIT: Solution that ended up working for me: Use these settings for the simulator
simulator.reset_integrator<drake::systems::RadauIntegrator<double>>();
simulator.get_mutable_integrator().set_maximum_step_size(0.1);
simulator.get_mutable_integrator().set_target_accuracy(1e-3);

and used this for the kinematics
    Eigen::Quaterniond qw_b{};
    qw_w.w() = 0.0;
    qw_w.vec() = curr_state.lin_vel_w;
    const auto rho = 10.0;
    Eigen::Vector4d q_dot =
        0.5 * (qw_w * curr_state.quat_wb).coeffs() +
        0.5 * rho * curr_state.quat_wb.coeffs() * (1.0 / curr_state.quat_wb.coeffs().squaredNorm() - 1.0);

where the extra term 0.5 * rho * curr_state.quat_wb.coeffs() * (1.0 / curr_state.quat_wb.coeffs().squaredNorm() - 1.0) is from equation (3) in https://publications.syscop.de/Gros2015.pdf

Will be curious to have the Drake dynamics team chime in. Short answer: yes you can definitely implement quaternion dynamics alongside other state variables (as MultibodyPlant does). For continuous-time models, I believe the recommendation is to implement the CalcTimeDerivatives method which is robust to non-unit quaternions (e.g. the method projects to a unit quaternion when reading from the context), and to implement a Baumgarte stabilization to drive the derivatives back to the unit quat. The integrators do not do active stabilization of constraints automatically.

For something like this I would use one of our error-controlled integrators. Error controlled integrators adjust the time step size used in simulation dynamically to ensure the solution is within a pre-specified accuracy. This will also do a good job at keeping the normalization within this accuracy. Try RungeKutta3Integrator, RungeKutta5Integrator or RadauIntegrator (this last one more stable).

Thanks for the input! Changing to RadauIntegrator with maximum step size 0.1 and target accuracy of 1e-3 does seem to improve a lot. I also found this paper: https://publications.syscop.de/Gros2015.pdf where they describe Baumgarte-esque feedback to help the quaternion stay unit norm.

